# image proxy registry not work for registry registry.k8s.io but work well for quay.io

Tags: docker, docker-compose, proxy, registry

### backgroud

- I use the [registry-proxy](https://github.com/yangchuansheng/registry-proxy/tree/1aba81152d3df2a406695a26646ca4461cb27a6f) (use docker registry's remote url ability actually) to set registry remote registry url that can let my local machine to be seen as a registry proxy. The expected result is the local proxy service startup on port 5005, then I can pull image like

```bash
sudo docker pull localhost:5005/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen:v20221220-controller-v1.5.1-58-g787ea74b6
```

to instead of

```bash
sudo docker pull registry.k8s.io/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen:v20221220-controller-v1.5.1-58-g787ea74b6
```

however, proxy registry.k8s.io not works as what I expected.

- What confuse me is that I start the registry quay proxy service by docker-compose setting like

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  dockerhub:
    image: yangchuansheng/registry-proxy:latest
    environment:
      - PROXY_REMOTE_URL=https://quay.io
    ports:
      - 5002:5000
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime
      - /var/lib/registry:/var/lib/registry
```

and I can pull image from the proxy service like

```bash
sudo docker pull localhost:5002/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator:main
```

It is strange that almost the same way to proxy, but registry.k8s.io not work and quay.io works.

- I deploy the registry service on aws cloud and I am sure the security group and other aws network setting is configured correctly.
- The issue not appear in my local mac, but only appear on aws cn-northwest-1 region's ec2. I deploy a clashx service to proxy the network traffic to ensure I can access the global network from china mainland

### How to reproduce the issue

1. use following docker-compose.yml to start registry proxy service on a host that can access registry.k8s.io

```bash
version: "3"
services:
  dockerhub:
    image: yangchuansheng/registry-proxy:latest
    environment:
      - PROXY_REMOTE_URL=https://registry.k8s.io
    ports:
      - 5005:5000
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime
      - /var/lib/registry:/var/lib/registry
```

```bash
## execute in the same path of docker-compose.yml
sudo docker-compose up -d
```

> tips: I am sure my host can access registry.k8s.io successfully with docker cmd:  sudo docker pull registry.k8s.io/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen:v20221220-controller-v1.5.1-58-g787ea74b6 ,and with this command ,the image on registry.k8s.io can be pulled

2. Execute docker command to pull the image from local proxy registry service

```bash
sudo docker pull localhost:5005/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen:v20221220-controller-v1.5.1-58-g787ea74b6
```

3. I am sure the proxy service is startup by the following command:

```bash
curl -I http://localhost:5005/v2/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Docker-Content-Digest
Content-Length: 2
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Sat, 02 Sep 2023 06:36:50 GMT
```

And I can't find any other error docker logs except the following error logs after execute pull image from local registry proxy service

```
time="2023-09-02T06:18:13Z" level=error msg="response completed with error" err.code="manifest unknown" err.detail="unknown tag=v20221220-controller-v1.5.1-58-g787ea74b6" err.message="manifest unknown" go.version=go1.7.6 http.request.host="localhost:5005" http.request.id=6f916c9e-5c18-4cb5-8d76-f659cbbc1d6b http.request.method=GET http.request.remoteaddr="172.22.0.1:41284" http.request.uri="/v2/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen/manifests/v20221220-controller-v1.5.1-58-g787ea74b6" http.request.useragent="docker/24.0.5 go/go1.20.6 git-commit/a61e2b4 kernel/5.15.0-1031-aws os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/24.0.5 \\(linux\\))" http.response.contenttype="application/json; charset=utf-8" http.response.duration=15.682908924s http.response.status=404 http.response.written=131 instance.id=fd110886-7135-4cc0-93cb-e87a24e8d206 vars.name="ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen" vars.reference=v20221220-controller-v1.5.1-58-g787ea74b6 version=v2.6.2-14-ga66a4c3
```